# EasyMock intercepts when setting a property

Tags: java, easymock

For example, I create an object, and want to set a property to it. The problem is, the property is never set, because EasyMock intercepts it. How to get around this?

```
ctx = control.createMock(EGContext.class);
ctx.setRequestSource("origin");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you understand how a mock works. You never need to set a value to a mock. You should tell the mock to return that value. The only exception is partial mocking when the class is testing itself but mocking part of its implementation.

But, in general, what you really want is

```
ctx = createMock(EGContext.class);
expect(ctx.getRequestSource()).andReturn("origin");
replay(ctx);
```

BTW, why are you using a control? You are using a really really old EasyMock version?